# How to caption more than one tabular

Tags: tables, captionof

I want to add a caption to 4 tables. The label should read "**tabular 1-4:** caption". My tabulars look like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
1&2\\
3&4
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
5&6\\
7&8
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
1&2\\
3&4
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
5&6\\
7&8
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{caption}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom style for the label and the separator, and apply it locally.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}


\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{customstyle}{\textbf{tabular 1-4}}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{customstyle}{\textbf{:}\space}

\begin{document}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        1&2\\
        3&4
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        5&6\\
        7&8
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        1&2\\
        3&4
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        5&6\\
        7&8
    \end{tabular}
    {\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=customstyle,labelsep=customstyle}
    \captionof{table}{caption}}
    
\bigskip
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        1&2\\
        3&4
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        5&6\\
        7&8
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        1&2\\
        3&4
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        5&6\\
        7&8
    \end{tabular}
    \captionof{table}{caption}
\end{document}
```

**Option 2**

Assuming that the first number (in 1-4) indicated the number of the set and the second the quantity of tabulars you can locally set the second locally using `\notabs`

[image: c]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcounter{nrotabs}% to set the numbers of tabulars <<<<

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{customstyle}{\bfseries tabular #2}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{customstyle}{\bfseries -\thenrotabs:\space}

\begin{document}
    
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        1&2\\
        3&4
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        5&6\\
        7&8
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        1&2\\
        3&4
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        5&6\\
        7&8
    \end{tabular}

    {\setcounter{nrotabs}{4}% set the numbers of tabulars
    \captionsetup[table]{labelformat=customstyle,labelsep=customstyle}
    \captionof{table}{caption x 4}}

    \bigskip
        \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        1&2\\
        3&4
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        5&6\\
        7&8
    \end{tabular}
    {\setcounter{nrotabs}{2}% set the numbers of tabulars
    \captionsetup[table]{labelformat=customstyle,labelsep=customstyle}
    \captionof{table}{caption x 2}}

\end{document}
```